# Why am getting pylint import and no member errors when I didn't before?

Tags: python, visual-studio, pytorch, pylint

Hi I've been working on this code for months without any of the pylint errors that have suddenly appeared? How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need pandas and torch installed in the same environment than the one you run pylint.

From the documentation at https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/error/no-member.html:

If you are getting the dreaded no-member error, there is a possibility that either:

- pylint found a bug in your code
- You're launching pylint without the dependencies installed in its environment.
- pylint would need to lint a C extension module and is refraining to do so.

Linting C extension modules is not supported out of the box, especially since pylint has no way to get an AST object out of the extension module.

But pylint actually has a mechanism which you might use in case you want to analyze C extensions. Pylint has a flag, called extension-pkg-allow-list (formerly extension-pkg-whitelist), through which you can tell it to import that module and to build an AST from that imported module:

```
 pylint --extension-pkg-allow-list=your_c_extension
```

Be aware though that using this flag means that extensions are loaded into the active Python interpreter and may run arbitrary code, which you may not want. This is the reason why we disable by default loading C extensions. In case you do not want the hassle of passing C extensions module with this flag all the time, you can enable unsafe-load-any-extension in your configuration file, which will build AST objects from all the C extensions that pylint encounters:

```
pylint --unsafe-load-any-extension=y
```

Alternatively, since pylint emits a separate error for attributes that cannot be found in C extensions, c-extension-no-member, you can disable this error for your project.

Comment: Thanks for this! How do I find the environment in which I installed pylint?

Comment: If you're not in your project's virtualenv you're probably in your IDE default env. It's hard to tell without knowing the specifics.